# div border overlapping button border, how to reverse it?

Tags: css, html, button, border

I'm having a problem with css and borders. I have [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LLVtr/) working well, but I want [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/GfENx/) working in the same way, I mean the ".current" buttom must have its right border (white) overlapping the ".simpleTabsContent" border, but it doesn't, it is behind the div border.

I tried with z-index but I got no changes. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

CSS code not working as I would like:

```
div.simpleTabs { width: 90px;float:left;padding: 0; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation { margin: 10px -1px 0 0; padding:0; text-align:left;}
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li { list-style:none; display:inline; padding:0; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button {
margin-bottom: 3px;width: 100%; color:#41635e; border:1px solid #6DA69D;
padding:3px 6px; background:#b6d2ce; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none; font-family: Verdana; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button:hover { background-color:#d3e4e1; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button.current {
background:#ffffff; color:#6da69d; border-right:1px solid #ffffff;}
div.simpleTabsContent { border:1px solid #6DA69D; padding:0px 5px 5px 10px; }
#msg{float:left;  width:350px;  padding: 5px 10px;  margin-top:10px;}
#container{ margin: 0; width: 500px; position: relative;}
```

CSS code working as I want:

```
div.simpleTabs { padding: 5px 0 0 5px; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation { margin:0 10px -1px 10px; padding:0; text-align:left; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li { list-style:none; display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button {
color:#41635e; border:1px solid #6DA69D; padding:3px 6px; background:#b6d2ce;
font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none; font-family: Verdana; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button:hover { background-color:#d3e4e1; }
ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button.current {
background:#ffffff; color:#6da69d; border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff; }
div.simpleTabsContent { border:1px solid #6DA69D; padding:5px 15px }
#msg{ margin: 0 5px 5px 10px;}
#container{ margin: 0; float: left; width: 450px;  position: relative;}
```

I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: The buttons and the content have a gap between them when the first fiddle is viewed in Chrome. Is this intentional?

Comment: No, the gap is not intentional, but it doesn't matther and is not what I'm asking for. What I want is to make the border right of the button ".current" to overlap the ".simpleTabsContent" border left. I'm using Firefox and the gap is not showing, I though it was the same in all browsers, I was going to post two images with the divs but it's not neccessary yet because Asad gave me the answer.

Comment: And sorry for those who saw the examples in chrome, I didn't notice about the gap in chrome. I must add some images, sorry, and thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by simply giving the two main elements the appropriate z-index values. To `div.simpleTabs` add:

```
position:relative; z-index: 2;
```

To `div.simpleTabsContent` add:

```
position:relative; z-index: 1;
```

Now the `simpleTabs` div overlaps the `simpleTabsContent` div, which means your changed border is now visible. Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/WEBnc/

Comment: This is what I want. This is what I asked for: right border of the buttom ".current" overlap the left border of the other div. I don't know why it didn't work for me before. Thank you.

Comment: I think, maybe it didn't work because of the "position:relative" that I didn't have before.

Answer (score 1):

The original link http://jsfiddle.net/LLVtr/ has a gap between the buttons and the message in the latest Chrome. By adding a margin to the message in version 2 will make it look the same though.

add to #msg

```
margin-left: 2px;
```

result:

http://jsfiddle.net/GfENx/3/

Comment: That is incorrect. There is now a gap between the buttons and the message.

Comment: Your css is incorrect then. Your provided link in Chrome has a gap as well. I just made it look the same as http://jsfiddle.net/LLVtr/ in Chrome

Comment: I didn't give you any CSS, nor did I give you a link.

Comment: Why did you downvote me then? I made the second fiddle look like the first. That was asked in the question. There was nothing related to gaps or not and I modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I viewed the page in Firefox, in which there is no gap between the buttons and the content in either of the original fiddles, whereas there is one in yours. I'll remove the DV since it isn't clear whether the OP intends for a gap to be present but it is highly probable she doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.simpleTabs { position: relative; width: 90px;float:left;padding: 0; z-index: 1; margin-right: -1px;}

ul.simpleTabsNavigation { margin: 10px 0px 0 0; padding:0; text-align:left;}

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li { list-style:none; display:inline; padding:0; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button { 
    margin-bottom: 3px;width: 100%; color:#41635e; border:1px solid #6DA69D; 
    padding:3px 6px; background:#b6d2ce; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration:none; font-family: Verdana; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button:hover { background-color:#d3e4e1; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button.current { 
    background:#ffffff; color:#6da69d; border-right: 1px solid #fff;}

div.simpleTabsContent { border:1px solid #6DA69D; padding:0px 5px 5px 10px; }

#msg{float:left;  width:350px;  padding: 5px 10px;  margin-top:10px;}

#container{ margin: 0; width: 500px; position: relative;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.simpleTabs { width: 90px;float:left;padding-right: 3px; }
```

Instead of padding:0; I have made it padding-right:3px;

http://jsfiddle.net/VS7fn/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.simpleTabs { width: 90px;float:left;padding-right: 0px; position: absolute;}

ul.simpleTabsNavigation { margin: 10px -1px 0 0; padding:0; text-align:left;}

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li { list-style:none; display:inline; padding:0; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button {
    margin-bottom: 3px;width: 100%; color:#41635e; border:1px solid #6DA69D;
    padding:3px 6px; background:#b6d2ce; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none; font-family: Verdana; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button:hover { background-color:#d3e4e1; }

ul.simpleTabsNavigation li button.current {
    background:#ffffff; color:#6da69d; border-right:1px solid #ffffff;}

div.simpleTabsContent { border:1px solid #6DA69D; padding:0px 5px 5px 10px; }

#msg{float:left;  width:350px;  padding: 5px 10px;  margin-top:10px; margin-left:90px;}

#container{ margin: 0; width: 500px; position: relative;
}
```

It will work for you.